# Retrieving BLOB data from an oracle table using select * with php/PDO

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

Is it possible to get the values of a BLOB/CLOB columns in an oracle database table that has more than 1 BLOB/CLOB column and most likely more that one row of data using a `SELECT * FROM table_name` Query.

example of such a table will be made as follows

```
CREATE table_name ( col1 CLOB, col2 BLOB );
```

example of the kind of query i'm trying to understand is

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

In all the tutorials/Articles i have reviewed while trying to solve this problem, the examples are only limites to selecting one cell i.e `SELECT column FROM table_name WHERE id = ?`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the PDO_OCI module doesn't fully support those data types. See the comments here:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

> After pulling my hair out for a day, it turned out to be a CLOB column
>   in Oracle that caused the strange behaviour in PHP. I assume this
>   extension doesn't fully support them.